# How to overlap the center of two divs when one has been resized and rotated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to find a "formula" which allows to overlap the center of two `divs` when one is **re-sized** and **rotated**.

Please look at this example and click in the following order: `button 1,2 and 3`.

http://jsbin.com/horiracudi/1/edit

You will see `div a1` has been `re-sized` and `rotated`.

When you click `button 4`,

- I need to adjust `div a1` `x,y position` so its center is exactly positioned
  on top of center for `div a0`.

This should work with:

- Any rotation
- Any size width/height of `div a1`

Possibly I need to keep `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Compensation could be added in function.

```
btn4.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    this.data.left -= this.data.width / 2; // compensation should be here
    this.data.top -= this.data.height / 2;
    this.render('a1');
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in your code and found that you change the default data property (`window.app.data`) every times you click your buttons. Therefore, when clicking the button 4, we have only the data of the `a1` div, while we need the data of both `a1` and `a0` div to calculate the position in your case.

I think this is not correct. We should store each element property separated and update its data only, so that you can track the `data` value of the `a0` and `a1` div when click button 4.

Another problem is the formula of calculate the position of `a1` div. It should be:

```
this.data['a1'].left = this.data['a0'].left + (this.data['a0'].width - this.data['a1'].width) / 2;
this.data['a1'].top = this.data['a0'].top + (this.data['a0'].height - this.data['a1'].height) / 2;
```

I have updated your code at: http://jsbin.com/gowegivuce/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

try this, you are re-sizing width and height with 2* so now the modified left and right will divided by 4.

```
btn4.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    this.data.left -= this.data.width / 4;
    this.data.top -= this.data.height / 4;
    this.render('a1');
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: thanks for your trying, but your answer does not answer my question as I need a solution which works with any dimensions of a1.. your code works only for on case of a1

Comment: what I really need is a mathematical formula